# CSS classes applied in wrong order

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a code which is working normal when used separately.

```
<div class="red green blue"> </div>
```

Now properties of `red` are applied first then overwritten by `green` then by `blue`. Finally, the `div` is `blue`.

But, when I load the same content in main application referring the HTML files by means of `angular include`, the order of CSS get reversed.

Now `blue` get applied first overwritten by `green` then by `red`. Now the `div` is `red`

This is breaking the code logic.

What is the possible reason if anyone has an idea.

Comment: If you're not using an attribute selector like `div[class="class1 class2 class3"]` the order of the classes in the element doesn't matter.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem, as CSS doesn't work the way described above, so something *else* is going on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Now properties of `red` are applied first then overridden by `green` then by `blue`

That's not how CSS works. The order of the classes in the class list has nothing whatsoever to do with the precedence of the rules those classes apply to the element.

CSS rules are applied by

- The *specificity* of the rule
- The order of the rule in the CSS (not the class list) relative to other rules with the same specificity (e.g., later rules win)
- Whether the rule has an `!important` flag

More in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade).

Example:

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red green blue">red green blue</div>
<div class="blue green red">blue green red</div>
```

Note that both divs have blue text (the color specified by `blue`), even though the first has `red green blue` and the second has `blue green red`, because all three rules have the same specificity, the `.blue` rule is the last rule in the CSS, and none of them is marked `!important`.

In contrast, let's make the `.green` rule more specific:

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
div.green {
  color: green;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red green blue">red green blue</div>
<div class="blue green red">blue green red</div>
```

Notice how the divs are now green instead of blue, because `div.green` is more specific than `.blue`, so the `div.green` rule takes precedence over the `.blue` rule even though `.blue` is later in the CSS.

Comment: Yes, the last rule must win .. But, when i load the html using angular include in main application.. the first rule gets precedence .. and violates the logic.

Comment: @atulquest93: Again: That's not how CSS works. Perhaps it would be useful if you added a [mcve] to the question demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Actually i have a sub application then needs to be merged in main application page. The sub application is working if used separately..but when its imported in main page the order of css get revered. So i'm stuck and not able to find the solution.

Comment: Can you explain why the second one is still green ? Or can we decide the order ourself.. as per our need.

Comment: @atulquest93: I *did* explain why the second one is still green (now blue; edited to match the edits to the question): See the second bullet point: *"The order of the rule in the CSS (not the class list)"*

Comment: @atulquest93: I've edited to expand on that and give a second example. :-)